# deleting mapStateToProps will give undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, react-hooks

I am React beginner, trying to convert class to hooks, need an advice/help on how to safely remove 'mapStateToProps ' without getting undefined.

i have page A.js and page B.js.

Component B.js i have posted whole code here so it is simple to understand.
At the moment console log will give me an array of objects.

If i remove 'mapStateToProps ' and set connect(null, null)(ConnectedList)

then console log will give me 'undefined'.

This is my A.js where i'm using component B.js:

```js
    <React.Fragment>
                <h3>
                  <Trans i18nKey="home.brokers">Brokers</Trans>
                </h3>
                <B action="brokers" actionArgs={site.identifier} />
                <h3>
                  <Trans i18nKey="home.cameras">Cameras</Trans>
                </h3>
                <B action="cameras" actionArgs={site.identifier} />
              </React.Fragment>
```

this is my B.js which i want to convert and get rid of 'mapStateToProps '

```js
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { connect, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  sites: state.articles.sites,
  analysers: state.siteArticles.analysers,
  brokers: state.siteArticles.brokers,
  cameras: state.siteArticles.cameras,
  platforms: state.siteArticles.platforms,
});

function ConnectedList(props) {
  console.log("data", props[props.action]);

  return <div></div>;
}

const B= connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ConnectedList);

export default B;
```

Comment: any advice/help is appreciated

Comment: Why don't you use `useSelector` hook from `react-redux`? It's made for function components to have access to the redux state from a hook, and you don't have to connect your store

Comment: @Martin i know about using useSelector , but how would you use it here ? where would you use it. I have added all B.js code

Comment: useSelector gets a callback function with which you can extract the part of the state easily: `const data = useSelector((state) => state[props.action]);`

Comment: could you use my code and give an answer so i can accept it ?

Comment: @Martin just tried still getting undefined

Comment: Maybe you get undefined becuse you have to extract the state from `state.siteArticles`, not just state:
`const data = useSelector((state) => state.siteArticles[props.action]);`

Comment: @Martin  this one worked: const data = useSelector((state) => state.siteArticles[props.action]); but im missing one of them, this : sites: state.articles.sites, how to get all of them ? can i combine result of those two selectors in one 'const' and use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use `useSelector` hook from `react-redux` to solve this problem.

As you can define any logic in your callback in useSelector you can easily extract the part of the state you need from props.action. If you want you can even lift this logic into a separate selector function then add it to your useSelector parameter.

```
export default function ConnectedList(props) {
  const data = useSelector((state) => {
    const articles = {
      sites: state.articles.sites,
      analysers: state.siteArticles.analysers,
      brokers: state.siteArticles.brokers,
      cameras: state.siteArticles.cameras,
      platforms: state.siteArticles.platforms,
    };

    return articles[props.action];
  });

  return <div></div>;
}
```

Comment: can you also answer this one, the collapsing part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69570020/uncaught-error-function-components-cannot-have-string-refs-we-recommend-using#69570020

Comment: I added typescript to it and getting error: interface A {
  action: string;
  actionArgs?: string;
}

const ArticleList: React.FC<A> = (props) => {
  const data= useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => {
    const articles = {
      sites: state.articles.sites,
      analysers: state.siteArticles.analysers,
      brokers: state.siteArticles.brokers,
      cameras: state.siteArticles.cameras,
      platforms: state.siteArticles.platforms,
    };

return articles[props.action]; }); Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)
(property) A.action?: string | undefined

Comment: any idea on this ?

Comment: with TS its a whole different question, please ask a new question with details and reproduction if you can't find your answer on SO

Answer (score 0):

We connect a Component to the **Redux** when we want to **read or change** a value.

Otherwise, there is **no need for Redux.**

Just skip it

```
export default Component
```

Comment: i did that but getting 'undefined' in console , it somehow needs that 'mapStateToProps ' to be there, without that getting undefined

Comment: I know that we connect a Component to the Redux in order to read or change but here i dont know why doing like this will give me undefined '
function B(props) {
  console.log("data", props[props.action]);

  return <div></div>;
}


export default B;
'

Comment: @joonas Why do you need to use `mapStateToProps` when you want to set its values to **null**?

Comment: i'm refactoring code which works, and converting to hooks, but here as you can see that 'mapStateToProps ' is not used inside B.js but when removing it i get undefined, any idea ?

Comment: Check your **Props** in your component.

Comment: everything is fine with props